# Updating Python Version of Docker

Tags: python, docker, openfaas

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 model B with Raspbian OS Lite x64. We are trying to upload a serverless function, but some of our libraries might not be compatible with Docker's Python 2.7 that is currently on there.

How do we update the version of python that Docker is using?

Comment: Is the serverless function a docker image? What do you mean by "Docker's python 2.7"?

Comment: Edit the Dockerfile and specify a different base image or install Python in the Dockerfile?